# Подскажите по mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite

Нужно чтоб с урла http://sub.domen.com выводилось http://domen.com/index.php?tl=sub.
Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domen.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.com/index.php?tl=sub [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если урл динамический, то есть http://domen.com/index.php?tl=sub1, http://domen.com/index.php?tl=sub2, http://domen.com/index.php?tl=sub3. Как это одним правилом прописать?